# How can I measure the memory required to run a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, resources

I am preparing a Jupyter notebook which uses large arrays (1-40 GB), and I want to give its memory requirements, or rather:

- the amount of free memory (*M*) necessary to run the Jupyter server and then the notebook (locally),
- the amount of free memory (*N*) necessary to run the notebook (locally) when the server is already running.

The best idea I have is to:

- run `/usr/bin/time -v jupyter notebook`,
- assume that "Maximum resident set size" is the memory used by the server alone (*S*),
- download the notebook as a **.py* file,
- run `/usr/bin/time -v ipython notebook.py`
- assume that "Maximum resident set size" is the memory used by the code itself (*C*).

Then assume *N* > *C* and *M* > *S* + *C*.

I think there must be a better way, as:

- I expect Jupyter notebook to use additional memory to communicate with client etc.,
- there is also additional memory used by the client run in a browser,
- Uncollected garbage contributes to *C*, but should not be counted as the required memory, should it?

Comment: What about `/usr/bin/time -v jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute notebook.ipynb`? Doesn't account for browser display memory though

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I have not tried this. Does it measure _M_ or _N_?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander That crashes with `jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named conda-env-python37-py` ('python37' is name of the conda environment  I use for the notebook's kernel).

Comment: The kernel name is not the name of your env. You can see your kernels with `jupyter kernelspec list`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I missed your comment, sorry. In every env I checked the only available kernel is "python3". Thus, I have no idea why in the notebook I could select "python37" kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is hard I think.

You have no guarantee that Python is actually putting in ram every variable. Maybe the OS decided to kick some of the memory on the disk using the swap.

You can try to disable it but there may be other things that cache stuff.

You can force garbage collection somehow in python using the `gc` package but results were inconsistent when I tried to do so.

I don't know if M and N are actually useful to you or if you are just trying to size a server. If it's the later, maybe renting increasing size server on AWS or Digital Ocean and running a runtime benchmark may actually give you faster and more reliable results.

Answer (score 1):

The jupyter-resource-usage extension is an extension preinstalled. It tells you how much memory you have and how much you need, but it's only available in the jupyter notebook you find in anaconda installations. It is located in the top-right corner.

Comment: Sadly, it is neither preinstalled nor working (for me). I needed to run `mamba install -c conda-forge jupyter-resource-usage` to get it, now I keep trying to get memory usage report (in the top right i have just "**Memory:**". If I manage to get  it working, I promise to start and grant you a bounty (for existing answer) given that no better answer appears in meantime. Almost forgot: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyter-server/jupyter-resource-usage/master crashed too :/

Comment: Found solution at https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-resource-usage/issues/64#issuecomment-870915461
Now I have something like: "**Memory:** 1.3 GB **Memory:** 2.4 GB" (two different estimates simultaneously).
Sadly it still does not capture the peak memory usage.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment, but hi again! This might not be what you're looking for, but try using Google Chrome's Developer Tools. There is a Memory section in it to see how much the website is using.